# Transforming two one dimensional arrays into one two dimensional array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays, both with the same length:

- x = [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 1439]
- y = [12, 55, 23, 46, ..., 99] (random Number between 0 and 100)

I wanna combine it to a two dimensional array like this:

- z = [[0, 12], [1, 55], [2, 23], [3, 46], ..., [1439, 99]]

How do I do it? Nesting, mapping?
Basically the first array is the key. In the end I wanna draw a line graph in D3 and all examples I have found use two dimensional arrays. One is the x axis, the other the y axis. Probably possible another way. Thanks

Comment: _"How do i do it?"_ -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

This did the sorting:

```
  s_arr = y_arr.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
  let neu_arr = [];
  let zz_arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 1440; i++) {
    neu_arr[i]= i;
    zz_arr.push([neu_arr[i], s_arr[i]]);
  }
  document.write("zz " + zz_arr + '<hr>');
  console.log(zz_arr);´
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = [0, 1, 2, 3] 
let y = [12, 55, 23, 46]
let z = [];
for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++){
  z.push([x[i],y[i]])
}
console.log(z)
```

convert it to 2d array like this

Answer (score 0):

```js
const newArray = [];
const x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1439], y = [12, 55, 23, 46, 99]

for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  newArray.push([x[i], y[i])
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, that helped.

```
     let min = 0;
        let max = 100;
        let x_arr = [];
        let y_arr = [];
        let z_arr = [];
        let z_ars = [];
        let z_arx = [];
        let z_arz = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
            var r = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
            x_arr[i]= i;
            y_arr[i]= r;

            z_arr.push([x_arr[i],y_arr[i]]);

            z_ars.push([y_arr[i]]);
            z_ars.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});

            z_arz.push([x_arr[i]]);
            
        }

        z_arx.push([z_arz,z_ars]);

        console.log(z_arr);
        console.log(z_ars);
        console.log(z_arz);
        console.log(z_arx);
```

Now I wanna sort the random data and put the two arrays together the same way. But it is not possible to create them separately and combine them the same way. Something has to be done differently.

This almost works but not quite:

```
            for (let i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
            var r = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
            x_arr[i]= i;
            y_arr[i]= r;
            z_arr.push([x_arr[i],y_arr[i]]);

            s_arr = y_arr.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});

            komplett.push([x_arr[i],s_arr[i]]);
        }

        console.log(z_arr);
        console.log(s_arr);
        console.log(komplett);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).